# Node memory leak investigation

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks

I am investigating a potential memory leak in my node API. I use heapdump to take snapshots, and it seems like the heap is rather consistent. (I took a snapshot every day for the past five days). However, when I `top` my memory usage for the process, the `%MEM` is slightly increasing every day. I wonder what causes the increase. Note: I use Foreman to manage the process and a lot of exec child process. Could it be memory leak from the libraries I am using?

Heap snapshot data:

2017-10-17 - 50.2MB

2017-10-17 - 50.8MB

2017-10-19 - 50.0MB

2017-10-20 - 49.5MB

Process memory usage on a 4GB Linux machine
It started with around 2.9%, last time I checked, it was 4.7%, now running at 5.3%.

Comment: If you could add some of your diagnostic data in your question, it would not be *so* broad.

Comment: Question updated with diagnostic data.

Comment: I think you have to just keep running it for longer and see if the process memory usage eventually settles in on a particular value or keeps going up and up and up forever.  Since the heap snapshot is not increasing, there does not appear to be a Javascript leak.  The remaining question is whether some part of the code that uses native code might be leaking.